# MySql: read database table entry which is next to timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql database storing the energy produced by an inverter. The values are stored summed up every x min in column "kWh_Dag". Now I would like to read, what energy has been produced that day up to a specific time of the day. The values are stored with the timestamp written "Datum_Dag".

I tried

```
SELECT `kWh_Dag` from `tgeg_dag` WHERE `Datum_dag` IN (SELECT MAX(`Datum_Dag`) FROM `tgeg_dag` WHERE `Datum_Dag` < "2013-09-27 00:00:00")
```

but the database does not return anything. The "inline" SQL statement does return the right timestamp belonging to the table entry which is the one I want.

Is this the smartest way to access the wanted database entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was using "IN". When changing to "=", the statement returns the wanted entry.

I assume that IN expects several values?!